# C# FOREACH on multiple LIST<> types

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Hi everyone and thanks for looking.

I'm not thinking this is possible, but I'd like to do an identical FOREACH through multiple returned LIST<> types without having to cut and paste the code 4 times.  All properties of the dto2, dto3, dto4, and dto5 lists returned are the same, except for the DataValue, which is a different data type for each (int, varchar, bool, etc.)

```
var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId);
var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId);
var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId);
var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId);

foreach (var x in dto2)
{
    var propertyInfo = dto.GetType().GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    { 
        propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
    }
}

foreach (var x in dto3)
{
    var propertyInfo = dto.GetType().GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
    }
}

foreach (var x in dto4)
{
    var propertyInfo = dto.GetType().GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
    }
}

foreach (var x in dto5)
{
    var propertyInfo = dto.GetType().GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `dto2`-`dto5`? Do they implement common interface of have common base class with `ShortDescription` and `DataValue` properties?

Comment: `ShortDescript` might return different values, right? So you might set different properties on `dto`.

Comment: @BrianRogers I don't get it. For me, it makes sense. Even though the type of all items in the list is the same, `ShortDescript` property can return different `string` values pointing to different properties on `dto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of solving that:

1. Assuming all `dto2`, `dto3`, `dto4` and `dto5` are collections of some type `T` that implements common interface with `ShortDescript` and `DataValue` properties declared on it.

   ```
   var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId);
   var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId);
   var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId);
   var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId);

   var source = dto2.Cast<MyInterface>
                    .Concat(dto3.Cast<MyInterface>)
                    .Concat(dto4.Cast<MyInterface>)
                    .Concat(dto4.Cast<MyInterface>);


   var dtoType = dto.GetType();
   foreach (var x in source)
   {
       var propertyInfo = dtoType.GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
       if (propertyInfo != null)
       {
           propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Without common interface you can use `dynamic`:

   ```
   var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId);
   var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId);
   var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId);
   var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId);

   var source = dto2.Cast<dynamic>
                    .Concat(dto3.Cast<dynamic>)
                    .Concat(dto4.Cast<dynamic>)
                    .Concat(dto4.Cast<dynamic>);

   dto.GetType() 
   foreach (var x in source)
   {
       var propertyInfo = dtoType.GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
       if (propertyInfo != null)
       {
           propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
       }
   }
   ```

   This will make `ShortDescript` and `DataValue` properties to be resolved at runtime and you'll get an exception when there is no such a property on actual type.

Comment: Brilliantly simple, Marcin, and exactly what I was looking for!  I used #2 and the dynamic cast.  There are a couple of typos in there, and Resharper had me eliminate a couple of unnecessary casts, so I pasted the exact code below in my own answer.  Tested and works exactly the same as my originally pasted code.

This is my first time asking a question on here after thousands of times looking for solutions, so I can't upvote anyone because I don't have a 15 reputation yet, or I would.  But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an all-reflection solution, you could make a method like this:

```
static void SetDtoFields<T>(object targetDto, IEnumerable<T> fields)
{
    Type fieldType = typeof(T);

    var fieldNameProp = fieldType.GetProperty("ShortDescript");
    if (fieldNameProp == null || !fieldNameProp.CanRead) 
        return;

    var dataValProp = fieldType.GetProperty("DataValue");
    if (dataValProp == null || !dataValProp.CanRead) 
        return;

    Type targetType = targetDto.GetType();

    foreach (T field in fields)
    {
        var propToSet = targetType.GetProperty((string)fieldNameProp.GetValue(field),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase );

        if (propToSet != null && propToSet.CanWrite &&
            propToSet.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(dataValProp.PropertyType))
        {
            propToSet.SetValue(targetDto, dataValProp.GetValue(field));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main code you can simply do:

```
SetDtoFields(dto, rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId));
SetDtoFields(dto, rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId));
SetDtoFields(dto, rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId));
SetDtoFields(dto, rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId));
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GhrJ0f

Comment: How are you going to access `DataValue` and `ShortDescript` properties on `x` when it's declared to be `object`? It won't even compile.

Comment: Good point, you'd need to use GetProperty there also.  I will edit.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question on here after thousands of times looking for solutions, so I can't upvote anyone because I don't have a 15 reputation yet, or I would.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. For your dto2,dto3,dto4,dto5 classes, make them share this interface:

```
public interface IDto
{
    string ShortDescript {get;set;}
    object ObjectValue {get;}
}
```

Implement ObjectValue on your objects (showing one as an example):

```
public partial class DetailBits // dto2 class maybe?
{
    public object ObjectValue
    {
        get
        {
            return DataValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create this function:

```
public static void SetValues(DTO dto, IEnumerable<IDto> items)
{
    foreach (var x in items)
    {
        var propertyInfo = dto.GetType().GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
               BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        { 
            propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.ObjectValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can do this in your main function:

```
var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId).Cast<IDto>();
var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId).Cast<IDto>();
var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId).Cast<IDto>();
var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId).Cast<IDto>();

SetValues(dto, dto2);
SetValues(dto, dto3);
SetValues(dto, dto4);
SetValues(dto, dto5);
```

Comment: This is my first time asking a question on here after thousands of times looking for solutions, so I can't upvote anyone because I don't have a 15 reputation yet, or I would.

Comment: No problem, if it helps you it's okay :) Just take special care with dynamic casts, it can get pretty dirty pretty quick. GL

Answer (score 0):

I used Martin's #2 dynamic cast solution with a few editing changes.  Works awesome!

```
        var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId);
        var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId);
        var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId);
        var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId);

        var source = dto2.Concat(dto3.Concat(dto4.Concat(dto5.Cast<dynamic>())));

        var dtoType = dto.GetType();
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            var propertyInfo = dtoType.GetProperty(x.ShortDescript,
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, x.DataValue);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, what it does is just take your DTO object, the collection and the name of properties to get and set.

```
    var dto2 = rd.EngDetailBitsList(dto.EngId);
    var dto3 = rd.EngDetailDateTimesList(dto.EngId);
    var dto4 = rd.EngDetailVarCharsList(dto.EngId);
    var dto5 = rd.EngDetailVarCharMaxesList(dto.EngId);

    ObjectSetter(new object() /* test only */, dto2, "DataValue");

    private void ObjectSetter(object dto, string dtoProp, 
        IEnumerable items, string itemProperty)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(dtoProp,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
            var itemValue = dto.GetType().GetProperty(itemProperty,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(item, itemValue.GetValue(dto));
            }
        }
    }
```

you can improve the performance of this by doing Asynchronous processing. call it like this

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate()
        {
            ObjectSetter(new object() /* test only */, dto2, "DataValue");
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate()
        {
            ObjectSetter(new object() /* test only */, dto3, "DataValue");
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate()
        {
            ObjectSetter(new object() /* test only */, dto4, "DataValue");
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate()
        {
            ObjectSetter(new object() /* test only */, dto5, "DataValue");
        });
```

Comment: negative vote w/o explanation, yea that sounds great

Comment: That was NOT me with the downvote, not sure who did it.  This is my first time asking a question on here after thousands of times looking for solutions, so I can't upvote anyone because I don't have a 15 reputation yet, or I would.

Comment: I didn't downvote either. But from what I can see, you're calling ObjectSetter with 3 parameters, but the function takes 4 parameters... Also 'IEnumerable items' without the type will probably not compile.

Comment: @RonaldEstacion In addition to what @Francisco said about the parameters, your code doesn't do what the OP was asking. It looks like you are reading the `DataValue` property from the DTO and setting some fixed property `dtoProp` on each item. What the OP is trying to do is get the `DataValue` from each item, and set a property on the DTO, the name of which is stored in the `ShortDescript` property on each item.